# How to get the mean value of every top 5% step in a tibble?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

For example:

```
data <- mtcars %>% select(wt, mpg, disp)
```

I want to get the mean values of each column for each top 5% step of `disp`. That will results 20 rows, the mean at top 5% `disp`, the mean at top 10% `disp`, the mean at top 15% `disp` ...

like this:

```
tops <- seq(.05, 1, by = 0.05)

# define list to save tibble of ecah LOPO
all_tops <- vector("list", length(tops))
names(all_tops) <- str_c("top", tops)

for (top in tops) {
    all_tops[[str_c("top", top)]] <- summarise_all(top_frac(data, top, disp), mean) %>% add_column(Top = top, .before = 1)
}

bind_rows(all_tops)
```

a more tidy solution, maybe not using `for`, is needed.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean `mtcars %>% 
  group_by(group = findInterval(disp, quantile(disp,seq(0.05, 1, 0.05)))) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(wt, mpg, disp), mean)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cut` to define which rows belong to which 5% band of `disp`:

```r
mtcars %>%
  select(wt, mpg, disp) %>%
  mutate(dispcut = cut(disp, c(-Inf, quantile(disp, seq(0, 1, len=21))[-1]), labels = FALSE)) %>%
  group_by(dispcut) %>%
  summarize_all(~ mean(.))
# # A tibble: 17 x 4
#    dispcut    wt   mpg  disp
#      <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1       1  1.72  32.2  73.4
#  2       2  2.07  29.8  78.8
#  3       3  1.51  30.4  95.1
#  4       4  2.39  22.2 114. 
#  5       5  2.14  26   120. 
#  6       6  2.96  22.1 131. 
#  7       7  2.77  19.7 145  
#  8       8  2.90  22.1 156. 
#  9      10  3.44  18.5 168. 
# 10      11  3.34  19.8 242. 
# 11      12  3.86  16.3 276. 
# 12      14  3.57  15   301  
# 13      15  3.48  15.4 311  
# 14      16  3.84  13.3 350  
# 15      17  3.39  16.3 357  
# 16      19  4.60  17.0 420  
# 17      20  5.34  10.4 466
```

Answer (score 1):

We use the `imap_dfr` function (from the tidyverse `purrr` package) to loop through each `disp` percentile limit (which we calculate with the `quantile` function), calculate the desired means, and return a data frame with the results.

```
library(tidyverse)

quantile(mtcars$disp, seq(0,0.95,0.05)) %>% 
  imap_dfr(
    ~bind_cols(
      disp.min.percentile=.y,
      disp.min=.x, 
      mtcars %>% 
        select(disp, wt, mpg) %>% 
        filter(disp >= .x) %>% 
        mutate(n = n()) %>% 
        group_by(n) %>% 
        summarise_all(list(mean=mean)) %>% 
        ungroup()
    )) %>% 
  arrange(desc(disp.min))
```

> ```
>    disp.min.percentile disp.min     n disp_mean wt_mean mpg_mean
>  1 95%                    449       2      466     5.34     10.4
>  2 90%                    396.      4      443     4.97     13.7
>  3 85%                    360       6      415.    4.48     14.6
>  4 80%                    351.      7      406.    4.29     14.8
>  5 75%                    326       8      399.    4.24     14.6
>  6 70%                    303.     10      382.    4.08     14.8
>  7 65%                    280.     11      374.    4.04     14.8
>  8 60%                    276.     14      353.    4.00     15.1
>  9 55%                    259.     14      353.    4.00     15.1
> 10 50%                    196.     16      339.    3.92     15.7
> 11 45%                    167.     18      320.    3.86     16.0
> 12 40%                    160      20      304.    3.75     16.5
> 13 35%                    146.     21      297.    3.73     16.9
> 14 30%                    142.     22      290.    3.68     17  
> 15 25%                    121.     24      276.    3.62     17.4
> 16 20%                    120.     25      270.    3.56     17.8
> 17 15%                    103.     27      259.    3.48     18.1
> 18 10%                     80.6    28      253.    3.41     18.5
> 19 5%                      77.4    30      241.    3.32     19.3
> 20 0%                      71.1    32      231.    3.22     20.1
> ```